# How do I retrieve and return an instance from my Class-Based Detail view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two linked models:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True)
    profile_page = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True)  

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am attempting to retrieve and return an instance of a single user's profile in this CBV:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    template_name = 'profile_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = self.kwargs.get('username')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user_profile)
        return obj
```

The `get_object_or_404` call causes the following exception: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'adam'`
"adam" because I am requesting the page url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/adam

Here are my url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^edit/', profile_edit, name='profile_edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)$', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
]
```

(Just in case: these also belong in the namespaced /profile/)

I'm trying to access the model fields within the Profile model. 
Why is it that I receive the error when trying to `return obj` to my profile_detail.html template?

What I've tried:
If I change the URL regex to accept ID or PK instead of `<username>` and access the url of /profile/1, I receive: `TypeError at /profile/1
__str__ returned non-string (type MyUser)`. If I then update my code to be:

```
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user_profile = self.kwargs.get('id')
    obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=user_profile)
    objj = obj.user
    return objj
```

then the errors clear and I can somewhat get things to appear on the profile_detail.html page. However, the `{{object}}` refers to the MyUser model, and not the Profile model as I desired.
What might be going on? Does it have something to do with

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

in the models?

edit: string method for my Profile model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user
```

Comment: That seems to be the `__str__` method for MyUser, you should show the one on Profile.

Comment: @DanielRoseman added in edits.

Comment: So, again, what is unclear about the error? You are clearly returning the `user` object from the str method, instead of a string which it expects.

Comment: @DanielRoseman One too many layers for me to follow. Much clearer now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are including the `username` in the url, not the user id. Therefore you need to change the `get_object_or_404` line as follows:

```
self.kwargs.get('username')
obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user_profile)
```

As the error message `__str__ returned non-string (type MyUser)` suggests, your `Profile.__str__` method should be returning a string, for example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Finally, you appear to have two `OneToOneFields`, `MyUser.profile_page` and `Profile.user`. This is unnecessary. If you remove the `MyUser.profile_page` field, then you can follow the `Profile.user` relationship backwards from `MyUser` to `Profile` with `user.profile`.